# Controller file was loaded but class does not exist in localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, file

i am new in magento

When i have setup my magento 1.9.0 website in local then after i am facing one error message during check out So can anyone please help me

```
a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist";i:1;s:873:"#0 E:\sam\htdocs\mytheme01\includes\src\__default.php(28528): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')
#1 E:\sam\htdocs\mytheme01\includes\src\__default.php(28496): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('E:\\Chetan\\htdoc...', 'WCL_CustomCheck...')
#2 E:\sam\htdocs\mytheme01\includes\src\__default.php(28383): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('WCL_CustomCheck...', 'index')
#3 E:\sam\htdocs\mytheme01\includes\src\__default.php(27971): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 E:\sam\htdocs\mytheme01\includes\src\__default.php(30837): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 E:\sam\htdocs\rolson\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 E:\sam\htdocs\rolson\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:151:"/mytheme01/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9yb2xzb24vY2xhbXBzLWNyYW1wcy8zcGMtZy1jbGFtcC1zZXQuaHRtbA,,/product/7899/form_key/RGCx0UYdMYYYhd8U/";s:11:"script_name";s:17:"/mytheme01/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: I see you have compilation enabled. Disable it and enable it again.

Comment: Yes i have try it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Point 1) This means magento was able to correctly require/include the file you placed your controller in but the controller class was misnamed. Controllers should be named

```
 Namespace_Module_ControllernameController
```

and located in the folder

```
 app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/controllers/ControllernameController.php
```

Point 2) Use the below code for override the checkout controller

```
 require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php"; 
 class Namespace_ModuleName_Checkout_CartController extends      Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
  {
    // code here ..
  }
```

Comment: ok let me check

Answer (score 0):

That error means that magento found a file for your controller where it expected to

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/XyzController.php
```

but that the class inside didn't have the name it expected like as

```
 Namespace_Module_XyzController
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry because i am not able to add comment so i have create my question in answer.

**Question:**
I have also face same issue but i have one question.

Why this problem occur in localhost only

All things are working proper in live  is there any specific reason

Thanks